# Methods that take strings

Tags: ruby, string

What is the simplest way to create a method that takes a string and an integer `x` and prints the input string `x` times?

Answer (score 7):

```
def i_times_s(s, i)
  i.times { puts s }
end
```

Comment: Doesn't get much simpler than that. Be careful when using reserved names like `method` though.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to look at things:

```
def string_times(string,integer)
  for i in 0...integer
    puts string
  end
end
```